# can not able to insert in sqlite database due to unrecognized token in db?

Tags: objective-c, iphone, sqlite, sql-insert

```
NSString * query  = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"insert into  tiger_%@  %@  values %@",modulearr[j],Qkey,Qval];
NSLog(@"query:%@",query);
sqlite3_stmt* stmt =NULL;
int rc=0;
rc =sqlite3_prepare_v2(Login, [query UTF8String], -1, &stmt, NULL);
if(rc == SQLITE_OK)
{
rc =sqlite3_step(stmt);
if(rc == SQLITE_DONE) //success
{
rc = SQLITE_OK;
}
sqlite3_finalize(stmt);
}
```

***Query Actual Result:***

```
insert into  tiger_Campaigns  (
actualsalescount,
modifiedby,
"assigned_user_id",
expectedroi,
campaigntype,
actualresponsecount,
numsent,
campaignstatus,
"campaign_no",
actualcost,
actualroi,
expectedresponsecount,
campaignname,
expectedresponse,
"cf_type",
modifiedtime,
id,
"product_id",
targetaudience,
createdtime,
budgetcost,
sponsor,
targetsize,
closingdate,
expectedrevenue,
expectedsalescount,
description
)  values (
0,
19x1,
19x1,
"0.00000000",
None,
0,
0,
None,
CAM8,
"0.00000000",
"0.00000000",
0,
"1-31",
None,
None,
"2017-01-03 07:09:02",
1x557,
None,
None,
"2017-01-03 07:09:02",
"0.00000000",
None,
0,
"2017-01-03",
"0.00000000",
0,
None
```

)

i am not able to insert using above query because it is contains special character in sqlite database telling UnRecognized token .

Comment: Show the actual values.

Comment: @Harshil Vyas add your query nslog

Comment: @Jigar - add query actual log

Comment: @CL. - show you actual query result

Comment: @Harshil Vyas you need to remove "" in column name

Comment: @HarshilVyas qkey is your array ?

Comment: @HarshilVyas try this [Qkey stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"\"" withString:@""];

Comment: @Jigar - Qkey is our array & Qval is also our array too.

Comment: @Jigar - i had already tried this [Qkey stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"\"" withString:@""] same result unrecognized token while executing sql.

Comment: @HarshilVyas but your Qkey is array so you can not replace it you need do replace string using for loop

Comment: What is that `1x557`? Shouldn't this be a strnig?

Comment: @Jigar - this is string  but error from sqlite is this only error: unrecognized token: "19x1":

Comment: @CL. -  it is 1x557 in text

Comment: @Jigar - any another way for this how to solve this issue

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try FMDB wrapper it will handle your array object as per its type. also handle special characters, quotes etc...

https://github.com/ccgus/fmdb

Search execute update with format method it will work for your query.

```
[DELEGATE.db executeUpdateWithFormat:@"INSERT INTO tbl_name (title, detail, type) VALUES (%@,%@,%@);",
             strTitle,
             [NSKeyedArchiver archivedDataWithRootObject:self.dictionary],
             @"Interest"];
if ([DELEGATE.db hadError]) {
     NSLog(@"error %@",[DELEGATE.db lastErrorMessage]);
} else {
    [DELEGATE showAlertLabel:@"Calculation Saved"];
}
```